# PEP8 Cleanup - Access to a protected member _last_executed of a class

Tags: python, pep8

I have the block of code below that traps warnings a few different query types and writes them to a lot and sends me a google chat message if they fail/warn. I get a pep8 error on `str(cursor._last_executed)`:

> Access to a protected member _last_executed of a class

Do I need to make changes on this? It does do what I want - sends mysql for failures to the log

```
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost", "root", "1234", "search")
cursor = db.cursor()
try:
    with warnings.catch_warnings(record=True) as w:
        if warn_type == 2:
            cursor.execute(query_string, kargs['field_split'] + kargs['user'])
        elif warn_type == 3:
            cursor.execute(query_string, (
                kargs['reportid'], kargs['timestamp'], kargs['reportid'], kargs['reportid'], kargs['timestamp']))
        else:
            cursor.execute(query_string, kargs['field_split'])
        db.commit()
        if w:
            logger.warning('Mysql Warning : %s', w[-1])
            logger.warning('Statement : %s', str(cursor._last_executed))
            logger.warning(kargs['field_split'])
            # noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences
            string_google = 'Warning - ' + str(w[-1].message) + ' - ' + str(cursor._last_executed)
            googlechat(string_google)
```

Comment: It is an undocumented, private attribute and you are not supposed to use it. If there is no way, however, to accomplish what you want you can simply ignore that warning.

Comment: you should not use that attribute, it is an not a part of the public API